# Show $\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|\leq\frac{1}{R^2-1}$ for $R>1$ and $z\in\text{Range}(\gamma_R)$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, inequality

> Define the semicircular arc $\gamma_R$ by $\gamma_R(t)=Re^{it}$, where $0\leq t\leq\pi$ and $R>1$ is a real constant. Let $\gamma$ be the join of $\gamma_R$ and the line segment from $-R$ to $R$.
>
> Show that, if $z\in\text{Range}(\gamma_R)$, then $$\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|\leq\frac{1}{R^2-1}.$$

My attempt:

Consider the inequality,
\begin{align}
|z^2+1|&\geq||z^2|-1|\\
&=|R^2-1| \ \ \ \text{(suppose $z=R>1$, such that $z\in\text{Range}(\gamma_R)$)} \\
&=R^2-1 \\
\frac{1}{|z^2+1|}&\leq\frac{1}{R^2-1} \\
\frac{|e^{iz}|}{|z^2+1|}&\leq\frac{|e^{iz}|}{R^2-1} \\
\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|&\leq\frac{e^{-\Im(z)}}{R^2-1} \\
\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|&\leq\frac{1}{R^2-1} \ \ \ \text{(as $z=R$ is a real constant by assumption)}
\end{align}
Is this correct? I am unsure if $z=R$ is a valid step. While this step does agree with the condition $z\in\text{Range}(\gamma_R)$, I'm unsure if the equality must work $\forall z\in\text{Range}(\gamma_R)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deductions that $|z^2+1|\ge R^2-1$ and $|e^{iz}|\le e^{-\Im(z)}$ both seem fine. However, your last step is quite dodgy. To finish off your proof, write $e^{-\Im(z)}=e^{-R\sin(t)}$ and use the conditions on $R$ and $t$ to conclude that $e^{-R\sin(t)}\le 1$.

Comment: Oh I see. I was thinking that because $R$ is a real constant, then $\Im(z)=0$. Is this not correct?

Comment: Since $R>1$ and $0\le t\le\pi$, we have $-R\sin(t)\le 0$, and thus $e^{-R\sin(t)}\le 1$.

Comment: If $R=2$ and $t=\pi/2$, then $\Im(z)=-R\sin(t)=-2\ne 0$.

Comment: and we're allowed to assume that $z=R$, as $z\in\text{Range}(\gamma_R)$?

Comment: Then how do we proceed from the first to the second line of my working and hence show that $|z^2+1|\geq R^2-1$?

Comment: No, we are not allowed to assume that. We have $z=Re^{it}$ for some $0\le t\le \pi$, and thus $z=R$ if and only $t=0$ or $t=\pi$.

Comment: Again, since $z=R e^{it}$, where $R$ and $t$ are both real numbers, we have $|z|=R$. Hence, by the reverse triangle inequality, $\lvert z^2+1\rvert \ge \lvert\lvert z^2\rvert-\lvert1\rvert\rvert=\lvert R^2 - 1\rvert = R^2-1$.

Comment: I think what i'm not understanding is why $z=Re^{it}$. It seems like an elementary step, but I don't get it.

Comment: What does it mean for $z\in\text{Range}(\gamma_R)$? It means PRECISELY that $z=R e^{it}$ for some $R>1$ and $0\le t\le\pi$.

Comment: This is where I have gone wrong. I assumed that $z\in\text{Range}(\gamma_R)$ meant that $z$  only took values on the imaginary axis from $0$ to $R$.

Comment: Well, the imaginary axis from $0$ to $R$ doesn't look like much of a semicircular arc$\ldots$

Comment: Yep, very silly mistake. Too much math and not enough sleep. I've also posted a second part of this question. I am having trouble find the integral of the LHS of the above results. That is, $$\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1} \ dz.$$